# twinx() and axhline

Tags: python, matplotlib

When using axhline right after twinx(), the horizontal line drawn still follows the coordinates of the first y-axis.

Any tip on how to make it scale to the second y-axis ?

Comment: It works fine in my setup. What is the code you are using?

Answer (score 2):

You could call the `axhline` method from the Axes objects, as in the example below, or set te current Axes with `sca`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = 2.0 * np.cos(x)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.axhline( 0.5, 0.1, 0.5, color='r', lw=3)
ax2.axhline(-0.5, 0.5, 0.9, color='b', lw=3)

ax1.plot(x, y1, 'r', lw=2)
ax2.plot(x, y2, 'b', lw=2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: @user2191437 If this solved your problem, please accept it (big gray checkmark on the left)

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't have access to the return value of `twinx()` (for example when it was called for you by Pandas) you can access the left and right axes using the Axes object's `left_ax` and `right_ax` attributes.

Only one of these will be present, as each links to the other axis.

- If you have a handle to the left axis, its `right_ax` attribute will point to the linked right axis.
- If you have a handle to the right axis, its `left_ax` attribute will point to the linked left axis.

For example:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'d1': numpy.random.rand(10), 
                       'd2': numpy.random.rand(10) * 10})
ax = df.plot(secondary_y=['d2'])  # returns the left axis
ax.axhline(y=0.5, alpha=0.5)      # draw a line from it
ax.right_ax.axhline(y=10, color="red", alpha=0.5)  # draw a line from the right axis
```

[image: Pandas plot() output]